# Why does my Submit button require 2 clicks before running desired script the first time?

Tags: javascript, email, onclick

I am new to java-script and have made this script to popup this custom message when a visitor submits an e-mail.  However, for some reason the 'display:block' only happens after the second time the user clicks "Submit" and not after the first click.  However, each subsequent time after that (unless the page is reloaded) the function works with only 1 click.  The only way I have been able to make it function as desired is by adding onLoad="eSubmit" to hte body tag (essentially taking the place of the first click), but I don't want to have to do that.  All applicable code I have is below... I would appreciate any help, thanks.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.alertbox{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
z-index:100;
display:none;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function eSubmit() {
    var msgBox = document.getElementById("msgSend");
    var responseTxt = document.getElementById("thanks");

   if(msgBox.style.display == 'block' || msgBox.style.display ==''){
      msgBox.style.display = 'none';}

   else{
      msgBox.style.display = 'block';}

   if(responseTxt.innerHTML == 'Returning to page...'){
        responseTxt.innerHTML = 'Thank you for submitting your e-mail.';}
}

function txtChange(){
    var E = setTimeout("eSubmit()",1000);
    var responseTxt = document.getElementById("thanks");

    if(responseTxt.innerHTML == 'Thank you for submitting your e-mail.'){
        responseTxt.innerHTML = "Returning to page...";
        E;} 
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="eSubmit()">

<div id="msgSend" class="alertbox">
    <div onClick="txtChange()">
        <p id="thanks">Thank you for submitting your e-mail.</P>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing, but look into this

```
   if(msgBox.style.display == 'block' || msgBox.style.display ==''){
      msgBox.style.display = 'none';}
```

The display property is set to an empty string even if there's an explicit setting inside . According to the W3C recommendation, .style-properties are only reflecting properties set inside the style=""-attribute of the element itself, not any computed or inherited settings defined elsewhere.

Because of that the if-statement becomes true and sets display to none on the first click.

Solution: change your if-else-logic or initialize the CSS display property as a style-attribute matching your needs

Comment: Well, apparently your idea was right.  When i switched the if/else logic it now works perfectly. However, I don't understand why?

this is the new code for the toggle section:

    if(msgBox.style.display == 'none'){
       msgBox.style.display = 'block';}
    else{
       msgBox.style.display = 'none';}

For some reason it works this way, but not the other way?

Comment: Edited my post. Can you post the mentioned `alert` using your old solution? That might clear things up. Put the alert in front of the if-statement

Comment: Ok, easy one: your css doesn't contain an initial value for display. Your if-statement checks for an empty string (==''), finds it because it is not initialized, evaluates true and jumps into the first block setting display to none. So your first click will always set display to none. If you accept the answer you might click the big outlined checkmark as well :)

Comment: but my css is set to 'display:none', thats what I don't understand, how is it not initialized? when the page starts the Div is not displayed (which is what I want), doesn't that mean I set it correctly?

Comment: `**display:none;**` is invalid css thus no css at all. you should remove the stars and try again

Comment: Haha, I only put the stars there so that people would notice that i had the property defined. In my actual css code the stars are not there at all, but the function still seems to not recognize that the display property is defined as 'none'.

Comment: I speculated about that. Have to rebuild your solution and debug that, gettin' back to you later

Comment: Thought that browsers would ignore that but use <style> instead of <script> for your css